# How to enable the swagger tool on mobilefirst Standalone server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have installed and configured the MFP 8.0 with WAS Liberty server in SIT environment after that I could not able to see the swagger tool in my operations console.

I have added below properties in my server.xml file

```
<!-- JNDI for the swagger ui, so the admin console can present a link
to open the adapter information in the swagger ui --> <jndiEntry
jndiName="mfpadmin/mfp.server.swagger.ui.url"
value="/doc/?url=/&lt;context&gt;/api/adapterdoc/&lt;adapterName&gt;"/>
```

After added above that properties in server.xml, the swagger tool button can able to see in operation console but after click the swagger tools was not working, I am getting " CONTEXT ROOT NOT FOUND " error

[image]

Comment: We do not install swagger by default  it as  a part of standalone install. this is only added by default as part of Devkit install.Can you check if the following is present.Please check and copy from IM package if not present.
<!-- Swagger UI  -->
    <application context-root="doc" id="swagger-ui" location="...../mfp-server-swagger-ui.war" name="swagger-ui" type="war">
    </application>

Answer (score 1):

Swagger is not installed by default in case of Standalone MFP setups. You can manually install and configure it to get swagger UI.

- To install:

  After installing IBM MFP 8.0 with the Installation Manager binary , you will find a “mfp-server-swagger-ui.war” file. This is not installed in standalone  case. You should install this war file manually and configure it - context root and JNDI. For the appropriate configuration, you can use the Devkit server.xml for reference.
  It is a war file and normal procedure to install war file ( specific to application server) should be followed .Thereafter , configuration ( JNDI and others) can be modified - in server.xml
- Configuration:

  Use Devkit configuration server.xml for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, I have successfully configured swagger tool features in standalone server, IO just copy the DEV kit server WAR files and configuration done my standalone environment.